Are bitwise operators slower than common loops like a for loop?
Do bitwise operators like & (AND) take more runtime than common for loops?
Today I was doing a power of 2 question in LeetCode. My code was this:
if (n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0) {
    return true;
}
return false;

It gave me a runtime of 5ms. I tried resubmitting to see if there was any variance in runtime but it was the same.
So then I wrote my code using a for loop:
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
    int ans = pow(2, i);
    if (n == ans){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;

The runtime became 0 ms.
I was hoping for a faster runtime with my bitwise operator code but instead I got the slowest one.

The only answer is the one given by profiling the code and verifying generated assembly, everything else is just speculation.

n - 1 is not a bitwise operation.

Unrelated: You first version could be simplified to return !(n > 0 && (n & (n - 1))); or return std::has_single_bit(n);

Most likely these timings don't mean anything at all except that the site is not benchmarking well. 5 ms is completely unrealistic for that piece of code and exactly 0 is also impossible. The second code also doesn't behave as the first one does. In particular, pow(2, i) doesn't do what you think it does. pow is a floating-point operation, not an integer one. Furthermore, if the second code was correct, there is no reason to believe that the compiler won't produce the exact same assembly from it as the first one. All in all, there isn't anything to this question except speculation.

A proper benchmark involves running the code a large number of times (billions) on different inputs, and verifying in some way that it is actually being executed rather than optimized out.

The truth is in the assembly language.  Create the two different functions.  Tell compiler to generate the assembly languages for both.  Compare the two assembly languages.

The call std::pow(2,i) can be replaced with (1 << i).  The shift is usually one instruction on most processors.  The function call is minimally 3 instructions and also has the overhead of branch prediction / evaluation.  Some compilers may perform this optimization at higher optimization settings.

pow on the other hand needs to handle really nasty stuff like pi to the power of e. For any simple exponentiation with whole numbers, it's usually total performance-killing overkill, in addition to imprecise, unless the compiler and the implementation of pow is really, really smart..

All of the common binary arithmetic and logical operations with the sole exception of divide take about the same time (often a single cycle) on modern computer architectures. Division can be 10-20x slower.
The problem here is with Leetcode's dodgy benchmarking. The second method is doing way more work! pow() has a significant execution time and is called 31x. There is no way that it can possibly win here.
The second loop could be rewritten to avoid the pow function call quite easily but even then it would still be doing around 20x more work than the first method.
bool better_forloop(const int n)
{
   int ans = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
   {
      if (n == ans) return true;
      ans *= 2;
   }
   return false;
}

@TedLyngmo makes a very valid point if statements and for loops each have an implicit additional cost for the conditional branch so that if you can compute a true/false result and return it then that is always better.
I altered the code to return an int and into classic C so that it would be minimal code on Godbolt. The results are interesting. GCC 14.1 made by far the best fist of it. Intel ICX less so and MSVC risible even at -O3.
This is the Godbolt assembler output from GCC 14.1 which was the densest and most efficient code generation I found. First method 8 instructions for any n, second method 11 + n*(10+time for pow()) ~120 (min) and a maximum ~3000 (when n=30).
bitwise:
    xor     eax, eax
    test    edi, edi
    jle     .L1
    lea     eax, [rdi-1]
    test    eax, edi
    sete    al
    movzx   eax, al
.L1:
    ret
forloop:
    push    rbp
    mov     ebp, edi
    push    rbx
    xor     ebx, ebx
    sub     rsp, 8
    jmp     .L7
.L12:
    add     ebx, 1
    cmp     ebx, 31
    je      .L11
.L7:
    pxor    xmm1, xmm1
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    cvtsi2sd        xmm1, ebx
    call    pow
    cvttsd2si       eax, xmm0
    cmp     eax, ebp
    jne     .L12
    add     rsp, 8
    mov     eax, 1
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    ret
.L11:
    add     rsp, 8
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    ret
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1073741824

A quick and dirty guestimate is that each instruction takes about 1 cycle on average except for call pow which is about 100 machine cycles. Pow has to compute log 2, multiply by i and then compute its exponential which takes ages.

Measurement with pow():

As already commented, Leetcode's benchmarking is not accurate at all.

We can simulate each function and simply time it with std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); and see a high-level overview of the measurements, which shows that the bitwise() solution is much faster:


#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

bool bitwise(const int n)
{
    return n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0;
}

bool forloop(const int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        int ans = std::pow(2, i);
        if (n == ans)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename Func>
long long timeit_with_steady_clock(Func F, int it)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < it; i++)
    {
        F(i);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
}

int main()
{
    const int it = 10000000;
    auto A = timeit_with_steady_clock(bitwise, it);
    auto B = timeit_with_steady_clock(forloop, it);
    std::cout << A << " ms vs. " << B << " ms" << "\n";

    return 0;
}



Prints
28 ms vs. 6705 ms


Measurement without using pow():

If we remove the pow(), the bitwise() solution is approximately 17 times faster than the forloop() solution, as well-explained in this answer:

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

bool bitwise(const int n)
{
    return n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0;
}

// Without using pow(): 
bool forloop(const int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        int ans = 1;
        if (n == ans)
        {
            return true;
        }
        ans *= 2;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename Func>
long long timeit_with_steady_clock(Func F, int it)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < it; i++)
    {
        F(i);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
}

int main()
{
    const int it = 100000000;
    auto A = timeit_with_steady_clock(bitwise, it);
    auto B = timeit_with_steady_clock(forloop, it);
    std::cout << A << " ms vs. " << B << " ms - Ratio of forloop/bitwise is " << B / A << "\n";

    return 0;
}


Prints
280 ms vs. 4860 ms - Ratio of forloop/bitwise is 17


Comments:

Sensibly timing the first code will be near impossible without additional context. It will only take a few cycles. For example loading the value of n from memory or even just cache will take longer than the actual operation. Values with which the function is called successively may cause significant branch prediction differences if there is a branch in the resulting assembly. The second code will be slower, but only because current compilers don't seem to do that particular loop-replacement I suggested. That one could be timed somewhere in the nanoseconds, but wouldn't be informative. – user17732522

All in all I think the only thing that OP can be told is that the loop will be significantly slower if the compiler isn't able to recognize that it can be optimized to a handful non-iterated instructions, which current compilers do not seem to be able to, but easily could. – user17732522

It's better to avoid high_resolution_clock and use steady_clock instead. – heap underrun



That doesn't benchmark anything worthwhile. You must have compiled without optimizations enabled, otherwise the compiler would have surely completely removed the loop that you want to benchmark for lack of side effects.

@user17732522 That's unnecessary. We're not looking into nanoseconds. We just want something simple to understand. Note that I did not say we're "benchmakring" in my answer, instead simply "simulating".

Compilers regularly replace loops with simpler instructions and the timing of few built-in expressions without optimizations enabled has practically no relation to the timing in properly optimized code. Only the latter actually has any practical relevance.

@user17732522 Why don't you just "benchmark" it and answer the question so that we see the time difference?

Sensibly timing the first code will be near impossible without additional context. It will only take a few cycles. For example loading the value of n from memory or even just cache will take longer than the actual operation. Values with which the function is called successively may cause significant branch prediction differences if there is a branch in the resulting assembly. The second code will be slower, but only because current compilers don't seem to do that particular loop-replacement I suggested. That one could be timed somewhere in the nanoseconds, but wouldn't be informative.

All in all I think the only thing that OP can be told is that the loop will be significantly slower if the compiler isn't able to recognize that it can be optimized to a handful non-iterated instructions, which current compilers do not seem to be able to, but easily could. (Also that calls to pow, which are wrong anyway, if not optimized away are orders of magnitude slower than anything else in their code.)
